# Form submit displays javascript coe instead of executing it

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, nodemailer

I'm trying to create an HTML form that will send an email using the information inputed. For now however, I just hard coded the information into the script itself, so the field inputs don't matter. However, whenever I press the Submit button, is simply displays the Javascript to the screen instead of executing it. The script is in the same directory as the HTML.

I tested it by running it directly from the Ubuntu terminal and successfully received an email from it.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 16.04, Node v6.14.3. The HTMl uses Bootstrap 4, and the email process is with Nodemailer. Thank you very much for your time.

-Joel

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'gmail',
 auth: {
        user: 'redacted',
        pass: 'redacted'
    }
});

const mailOptions = {
 from: 'redacted',
 to: 'redacted',
 subject: 'hey',
 text : 'text',
 html: '<p>Your html here</p>',


 attachments:[
  {
   filename: 'anglerite.png',
   path: '/home/joel/Desktop/Anglerite/img/anglerite.png' 
  }
 ]
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
   if(err)
     console.log(err)
   else
     console.log(info);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">



    <title>Redacted</title>
</head>

<form" class = "col-sm-6" action = "app4.js" method = "POST" > 
     <div class = "row form-row form-group">
     
      <div class = "col-sm-5">
       <input type = "text" class = "form-control-plaintext full-width" id = "name" placeholder = "Your name here">
      </div>

      <div class = "col-sm-2">
      </div>
     
      <div class = "col-sm-5 widen-slightly">
       <input type = "text" class = "form-control-plaintext full-width" id = "staticEmail" placeholder = "email@example.com">
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class = "row form-row form-group">
      
      <div class = "col-sm-12 widen-slightly">
       <input type = "text" class = "form-control-plaintext full-width" id = "phone" placeholder = "Phone number with area code">
      </div>

     </div>

     <div class = "row form-row form-group">
      
       <div class = "col-sm-12 widen-slightly">
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control-plaintext full-width" id = "subject" placeholder = "Subject">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class = "row form-row form-group">
      
       <div class = "col-sm-12 widen-slightly">
        <textarea rows = "6" class = "form-control-plaintext full-width" id = "Description" placeholder = "Description"></textarea>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class = "row form-row form-group">
      <label  class = "col-sm-3 col-form-label" >Any Photos</label>

      

      <div class = "col-sm-7">
       <input type = "file" class = "form-control-file full-width" id = "">
      </div>

      <div class = "cl-sm-2"> 
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id = "submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
     </div>


      
     
    </form>
```

EDIT: Chris Happy's answer proposed moving the Javascript from an external file referenced only by the action property, to references to a  in the same page.

Comment: Does your form action look like `action="/script-file.js"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are redirecting to your script file rather than running the code on submit.

In other words, your form looks something like this:

```html
<form action"script-file.js" method="GET">
  <input type="text" value="Some text">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

However, that will redirect to your script file and it will display on the browser as plain text.

Instead, display your form and code like this:

```html
<form id="myForm" action="/" method="GET">
  <input type="text" value="Some text">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>


<!-- Use: <script src="myscripts.js"></script> or -->
<script>
  const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

  myForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: 'redacted',
        pass: 'redacted'
      }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'redacted',
      to: 'redacted',
      subject: 'hey',
      text: 'text',
      html: '<p>Your html here</p>',


      attachments: [{
        filename: 'anglerite.png',
        path: '/home/joel/Desktop/Anglerite/img/anglerite.png'
      }]
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
      if (err)
        console.log(err)
      else
        console.log(info);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Uh oh, I'm terribly sorry. I had to repost my question on account of an unspecific error that stackoverflow was throwing, and it seems that I didn't include my HTML form code in my final post. My script is now executing, so your solution worked. I'm now getting a different error, but since it is different, I should probably post it as another question. Thank you for the help!